# Integrate Magento REST API (OAUTH1.0) with SAP PI

Tags: magento-1.9

I am trying to integrate SAP PI system with MAGENTO for REST API service with OAUTH1.0.
I have consumer key, consumer secret, token key, token secret.
Using java code, I am able to create TIMESTAMP and unique NONCE values.
However, I am not aware, how to generate oauth_signature?

Can somebody please help me out here?

Here is what I need to put at HTTP Header level -

Authorization -

OAuth oauth_consumer_key="xxxxxxxxxxx",oauth_token="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="1507730584",oauth_nonce="8NdIsk",**oauth_signature="6g%2FEXBnicV%2FsDjxw933bg5Yo2QA%3D"**

BR,
Rashmi